# Ruby: "in `<=': comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby, numbers

Hopefully something less newbish than my last...

Anyhow, I am doing a bit of coding on a small app that simplifies numbers down to primes, mainly to help with small things like homework.

However, a particular method is giving me the error mentioned in the title:

```
def get_simps(num)  
  curr = 2  
  print("Working...")  
  while (curr <= num)  
    #If they divide cleanly, then it's a simplified form  
    if (num % curr == 0)  
      res = [curr, num / curr]  
      break  
    end  
    curr += 1  
  end  
  print("\n")  
  return res    
end
```

Where the argument *num* is supplied by this statement:

```
print("Insert number here: ")  
num = gets().chomp().to_i()
```

Thus making the error weird: why does it say I compare a Fixnum and an ARRAY? I also did this:

```
if (num.class() == curr.class())  
 print "Cheese"  
end
```

and it printed Cheese. Why the reason for the error, then?

Comment: Copypasting into IRB and calling with `get_simps(gets().chomp().to_i())` doesn't give me an error (although it does give wrong results: get_simps(15000) => [2, 7500]

Comment: The code you've posted works fine for me.  Are you doing something like `get_simps(get_simps(20))`?

Comment: Also, "wrong" since I was expecting it to return a prime factorization of the number.

Comment: @Tordek Actually, this looks like a way of detecting primes, and it'll return the factor and what the result of dividing by that number would be, or `nil` if prime.

Comment: @new123456 A full backtrace and perhaps the purpose of this program would help a lot here.

Comment: @Tordek. It's meant to be used in conjunction with another, simplifying algorigtm in the same code. I'll post it if you want to look at it.

Comment: @David: No, I'm using a method to simplify called simplify, which expects an array or a number, like simplify(get_simps(num)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as published doesn't look like it should give the error described unless you inadvertently feed it an array.

You might want to look at the divmod() function, which could clean up the inner loop somewhat. And you're going to perform a lot of unnecessary integer divisions should your smallest prime factor be large.

It's not the answer you're looking for, but a particularly elegant Ruby prime factor solution can be found [here](http://www.benrady.com/2009/12/katarubytail-recursive-prime-factors.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I rewrote the entire algorithm (crap-o-rithm) from scratch, and it seems okay on performance.